# javascript datetimepicker my textbook values got lost

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have very easy javascript question. 
I used a javascript in my asp.net project My page has dropdownlist and it reflesh the page and in every reflesh The values that are in my textbook that holds the values from javascript got lost How I can keep the values?

```js
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
</script>
```